# LocationListener Network provider not called

Tags: android, location

I'm facing a really annoying problem. In some point of the program, I
need to track the user position. For that I register a listener for
all the providers available and request updates. This was working
really good until I updated my phone to Android 4.0. But the same code
is working perfectly in older versions.

Now, the listener is not being called. But only under some conditions:

- if i have gps coordinates, this works perfectly ok, even if the gps
  coordinates are lost, I get also network
- but if there is no gps coordinates and there is no wifi signal (but
  the wifi on the phone is enable), I should be able to get the
  coordinates using the 3g. Here is were it's not working. If I debug, I
  can see how the listener is being registered but it is never called.

Please, help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know whether you have gone through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html). 
If not, it would be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sim card in the device? I found this resolved the issue for me.

Incidentally, I found that after I upgraded my Galaxy Nexus to Android 4.x (specifically, 4.2.2) weird things started happening with my device. Perhaps this there are some bugs in the updates?